# Having unique text in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I making a MCQ app and I need to maintain unique questions and their choices in the database so I cant have more than one question with the same question string and choices. But how should I make that efficiently?! I have the question strings saved in the database as TEXT type in a table and another table containing the choices as a one to many relationship does any one have any thoughts? as I think making the question string as unique would be very slow right?!

Comment: who adds the questions? what if question 1 is "what colour is the sky?" and question 2 is "the sky is what colour?

Comment: you could add a prefix index or and extra column with a fast hash function of the text, but as Dagon says, human-entered questions will not be exactly the same. Another approach would be to use a fultext index for fuzzy search and refuse insertions if the new question is too similar to a previous one.

Comment: yes, instructors add the questions and it should select random questionts to be shown to student on his quiz so it will be very bad to have multiple repeated questions in the same quiz, so basically I was wondering that when instructor finishhis questions it can search database for similar ones and prompt him with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you need to maintain unique questions in your database. I've a suggestion in which we can find out the keywords (Tags) of from the Question String. To find out the keywords (Tags) from the question we can use 2 ways.

### **1. Tags:**

When a question is inserted. we can also take the tags which is related to Question.
For Example:

> Q1. What colour is the sky?

**Tags:- colour, sky**

> Q2. The sky is what colour?

**Tags:- sky, colour**

### **2. Finding the tags automatically**

Here we can put the normally used words in table of DB like

**Helping Verb.**

be, do, have, is, does, had, are, did, has, am, were, was, being, been

**Articles**

The, A, An

**Five Ws**

When, Who, How, Why, What, Where

you can find more like that and then we acually subtract this words (keywords/tags) from the string and find the tags automatically.

Either ways we find out the tags. after finding the tags

### Conclude

Letz say if we found 20 tags in a question then we can query that if a question match morethan 15 tags will list and thus can find whether the question is repeat or not.

Comment: how should questions be linked with tags in database i mean? how to compare new tags with already existing ones?! last question depend on how would it be saved in db

Comment: If your db is all ready you can make a new table which consist of QuestionID and Tags to Foreign relationship or you can add a column **TAG** in your table containing questions and add all the tags in one field separated by comma.

Comment: and should I make index search on all tag field with the new tags?!

Comment: You can actually apply indexing and after that there were 2 ways to search one would be 
[SQL IN Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)
and second
[Full text Search - Match Against](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: If you like the suggestion and found the solution mark it as answer and upvote. Thanks in advance :)